# Dataframe split rows into new columns - X, Y coordinates & Text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text

I have text that is already in a Dataframe that typically looks like this:

```
Column
100,    1594, text & or numbers $124,345.56
108,    1805, _ _ _
254,    2000, (13,452,863)
```

There 4 spaces in between the first series of numbers and the second which are X, Y coordinates then the text.  How would I get it into a new data frame like this:

```
  Y       X   Text
100    1594   text & or numbers $124,345.56
108    1805   _ _ _
254    2000   (13,452,863)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one solution, given the input data you have supplied.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column': ['100,    1594, text & or numbers $124,345.56',
                              '108,    1805, _ _ _',
                              '254,    2000, (13,452,863)']})

df_out = pd.DataFrame(df['Column'].str.split(', ').values.tolist(),
                      columns=['Y', 'X', 'Text'])

df_out[['Y', 'X']] = df_out[['Y', 'X']].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='integer')

#      Y     X                           Text
# 0  100  1594  text & or numbers $124,345.56
# 1  108  1805                          _ _ _
# 2  254  2000                   (13,452,863)
```